# PHP Whoops error handle clear buffer

Tags: php, error-handling, whoops

**Issue**

In procedural scripting the PHP Whoops Pretty Page handler content will be mixed with partial content from the applications buffer output.
Whoops can appear scrambled or output inside a hidden html tag.

**Question**

How to clear the previous buffer before Whoops handler buffers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution worker for me:

> At the earliest point of your script and perhaps only in a DEBUG or DEVELOPER mode as I did you need to do:

```
if(DEVELOPER_DEBUG === true)
    ob_start();
```

Then where you declare Whoops I did:

```
if(DEVELOPER_DEBUG === true)
{
    $_whoops = new \Whoops\Run();

    $_whoops->pushHandler(function(){
        ob_clean();
    });

    $_handler = new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler();
    $_whoops->pushHandler($_handler);
    $_whoops->register();
}
```

This worked flawlessly in my usage case in procedural scripting to clear any initial generated buffer before Whoops starts it's own output.

**Why it works**

ob_start() can be called multiple times, the buffer *flush* or *clear* function needs to be called the same number of times as start was called in sequence.

By making your application start its own buffer it makes it a resource that can be cleared, Whoops always starts it's own buffer as well, so by registering a handler to clear the first buffer (your application) then on the event of an error, Whoops can clear that previous buffer.

**Buffer Control**

For example, each call of **ob_start** an incremental buffer is created.

If you call ob_start 3 times you need to call ob_flush 3 times in order to output all buffered content.

If you call it once you will only clear or flush the content generated before the next ob_start was declared.

Could be adaptive for OOP.